# What does password cracking depend on most

Tags: password-cracking

Does it depend more on processing power or on Internet Bandwidth?

Are there any numbers on the effect of both?

I mean for passwords of web applications (email, etc...)

Comment: Why Internet Bandwidth? if you are Password cracking, you have already the Password(s) on your computer. Further more, I think this question is far to broad because there are many factors where it could depend. It can be RAM, it can be CPU, it can be GPU, Harddrive,... etc. It all comes down to the algorithm(s)  used

Comment: For an answer, it is very rare to be cracking password on live servers, usually password cracking is done against downloaded database.

Apart from this answer I flagged this question as it is too broad.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong term. "Password cracking" is different from brute forcing access to an online account.

Comment: CPUs can run much, much faster than your Internet speeds, so the CPU is not a bottleneck. The service itself is the bottleneck to brute forcing.

Answer (score 4):

All serious web services has some kind of rate limiting, so cracking anything but the weakest passwords "online" is normally not an option.

Instead, password cracking is usually done "offline" on hashes that has somehow leaked. This off course requires there to be some kind of data breach that makes them available, but [there are plenty of these](https://haveibeenpwned.com/PwnedWebsites).

That said, if you were to try online cracking against a server without any rate limiting, the important thing would be the speed of the internet connection and the processing power *of the server*. Your machines processing power isn't relevant, since it is the server that has to do the hard work of handling the request and hashing the password.

Not sure what kind of numbers you want, but I don't have any anyway.